# Shift+Select a edges of a mesh after applying array modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

here's my problem, I made a curve from a mesh outline, this mesh was itself created from the array modifier.

When using the array modifier, the command for shift+select only selects the piece of the original mesh used in the array.

Ex:
[image]

So my question is, is there any way for blender to recalculate what is a selectable line, even if I have to do it by juntion, this could sabe a lot of time in the future.

My objective here would be to convert this edge into a new curve, and so create a rail from an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hadn't enabled the Merge option in the Array Modifier, although they are in a single object, each duplicate of the mesh created by the array will be separate. To be able to select the entire line of edges, they need to be a single mesh. To join them, select all with A > press M to merge > click on By Distance. This will merge all the duplicate vertices together, giving you one single, continuous mesh. You can also specify a distance threshold.

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I needed